# Uploading PDF documents to a SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, service

We have a scanner that is going to scan documents into a specific directory.

I need ideas on where to start on an application/service  that I can schedule to run every hour or so and upload the documents to a Cloud DB.

Every single example I can find involves the uploader that requires a user to browse/select the file; I don't want that.

The documents will be stored as binary if that matters.

Comment: There a million and one ways to do this depending on the OS of the "specific directory" and the the OS/type/server of the "Cloud DB". You'll have to be much more specific about the problem you are running into.

Comment: We have a scanner that is going to create PDF files of scanned documents and dump them into a specified directory.  I need to upload the documents from that specified directory into a table on a Cloud server. This needs to happen without requiring the user to browse and select documents one at a time through the uploader tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you get started. Build a console app that does something along these lines

```
void Main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\your\\path\\here\\","*.pdf");
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            UploadToCloudDB(file);
            //possibly delete the file now
        }
        Thread.Sleep(30000); //pause for 30 seconds between scans

    }
}

static void UploadToCloudDB(string path)
{
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    //upload those bytes to the cloud DB ....
}
```